# Convert a string to date format

Tags: string

In Unix i have a file which has information like below

```
$ cat date.txt 
Mon Apr 8 21:00:42
```

I Need to convert this as `2019-04-09 00:29:22`.

Example:

```
$ cat date.txt 
Mon Apr 8 21:00:42
```

--
expected o/p

```
Mon Apr 8 21:00:42
```

Comment: hm, I don't see how you convert `21:00:42` to `00:29:22` or is it just a bad example ? also your expected o/p is the same as the input. Please fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date`:

```
date -d "Mon Apr 8 21:00:42" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

or

```
date -d "Mon Apr 8 21:00:42" "+%F %X"
```

For all lines of a file:

```
xargs -a date.txt -I{} date -d "{}" "+%F %X"
```

---

See [`man date`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date) for the FORMAT specification.